# canvas.create_image not displaying image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have an interesting issue that I can't appear to solve. The following piece of code should display a smaller image ontop of a bigger image which is situated on a Tkinter canvas:

```
x = int(int(self.city[3]))-self.left
y = int(int(self.city[2]))-self.upper
print x, y
self.target3 = self.canvas.create_image(x, y,image=self.cross, anchor='nw')
time.sleep(2)

#--------TO THROW ERROR
self.target3.image = self.cross
#--------
#self.canvas.delete(self.target3)
self.gameplay()
```

self.cross is declared earlier on the program with

```
self.crosshairs = Image.open("targetcrosshair.gif")
self.cross = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.crosshairs)
```

I know it is not a problem with the garbage collection that others seem to have fallen fowl of because without this section of code the image is still used fine repeatedly in the main loop.

As part of my search for a solution I added the  self.target3.image = self.cross piece of code which caused it to error, and then my image spontanously appeared as it should do. Any idea why the image only appears when an error is thrown?

Also, I have checked the x and y values and they should fall on the canvas, and they do which is shown when I force an error.

Comment: Please try to create the smallest possible _complete_ working program that illustrates the problem. Without that, it's very hard for us to help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Are you running `mainloop`? It could be that the image appears after the error because the error triggers an update, which causes the screen to be refreshed. The call to `sleep` also contributes to the problem; while the app is sleeping, no updates to the screen are possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't really strip it down, it is quite beastly. Your hints have helped though and I have solved it. You were right that it was a problem with sleep, calling root.update() caused everything to update correctly thank you!

Comment: Bryan points is right. Need define under '__init__' before to `mainloop`

Comment: @SamuelBarnett: you don't have to strip it down. Create a new app with just the code that illustrates the problem. Often, the process of writing code to reproduce the problem helps you realize what you've done wrong.